# A general way to enclose database code in transaction with delegates?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, delegates

I ran into the "problem" that I'm quite often now reusing/copy'n'pasting code that checks if a nHibernate *ISession* is currently in a transaction and if not starts one.

Now I thought it would be nice if I just made a static method in a utility class that I can provide with an *ISession* object and a delegate that contains the actual database code and then use just that method to encapsulate that stuff in a transaction if there wasn't one ongoing just yet.

So here's what I came up with.

```
public static class TransactionUtils
{
    public static void EncloseInTransaction(ISession session, Action<ISession> codeToEnclose)
    {
        if (session == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("session");

        var isInTrans = session.Transaction != null && session.Transaction.IsActive;

        var tx = isInTrans ? session.Transaction : session.BeginTransaction();

        try
        {
            codeToEnclose(session);

            if (!isInTrans)
                tx.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tx.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!isInTrans)
                tx.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

So this is all nice and well I guess. But using that code looks something like this.

```
TransactionUtils.EncloseInTransaction(session, session1 =>
{
    session1.Query<Blahblah>().Where(x.Blub == "meh").ToList();
    session1.CreateQuery("update Foo set Urgs=:Moo where Id=:Id")
        .SetParameter("moo", "baaahh")
        .SetParameter("Id", 12305)
        .ExecuteUpdate();
} );
```

I don't really like the *(session, session1 =>...)* part here. Looks confusing as hell and someone could just use *session* instead of *session1* inside the code passed to the delegate.

So basically my question is. Would it actually be a problem if I ditched the `Action<ISession>` and replaced it with only `Action` and then just used *session* inside the code? I know there's much magic happening there but as i understand it if i reference *session* inside the delegates code the compiler provides a pointer to the *session* object inside there. Or something or other. And i could basically just use that.

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, but in your example there is no point in explicitly using a session, a single update statement is implicitly transactional, it will either work or fail. Hopefully you are not using it like this in the real world, but I have seen this pattern many times.

Comment: Yeah the example is very simplified. But addressing the implicit transaction. I am using NHibernate Profiler and it is always marking the implicit use of transactions as a possible performance problem. So i'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make that method an extension method, that should make the code look much nicer.

```
public static void EncloseInTransaction(this ISession session, Action<ISession> codeToEnclose)
```

And calling the method:

```
session.EncloseInTransaction(s =>
{
    s.Query<Blahblah>().Where(x.Blub == "meh").ToList();
    s.CreateQuery("update Foo set Urgs=:Moo where Id=:Id")
        .SetParameter("moo", "baaahh")
        .SetParameter("Id", 12305)
        .ExecuteUpdate();
});
```

You can also use `Action` like you said (which is ok) and it would look like this:

```
public static void EncloseInTransaction(this ISession session, Action codeToEnclose)
```

Calling the method:

```
session.EncloseInTransaction(() =>
{
    session.Query<Blahblah>().Where(x.Blub == "meh").ToList();
    session.CreateQuery("update Foo set Urgs=:Moo where Id=:Id")
        .SetParameter("moo", "baaahh")
        .SetParameter("Id", 12305)
        .ExecuteUpdate();
});
```

Comment: Damn... Yeah! Why didn't i think of that... Thanks a lot.

Comment: I will as soon as i am allowed to. And thanks for clarifying further.